# Firebase object value return only if condition is met

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this data strucutre in firebase [image]

I want to query ONLY the values that have "absent"

I tried to do an equal to:

```
this.props.firebase.getLastAttendanceDate(organization)
.limitToLast(daysBack)
.equalTo('absent')
.once('value')
.then(
  snapshot => {
    const attendanceForSelectedRange = snapshot.val();
    console.log(attendanceForSelectedRange);
  }

)
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the database to be able to access the attribute name, for example in your database you can do the following:

```
db.ref("12-27-2019-PM").orderByChild("-Lwk9IT19HHCHw9e-3vq").equalTo("absent").once('value')
.then(
  snapshot => {
    const attendanceForSelectedRange = snapshot.val();
    console.log(attendanceForSelectedRange);
  }
```

`equalTo()` is used with `orderByChild()` where you pass the name of the child to that method

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write